# Shortcuts for testing out small code snippets in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA and was thinking about how nice it would be to be able to pop up a context where I could write, compile and run some simple core java code and then automatically dispose of the whole thing when I close the context.

Sometimes you just want to try simple something out, like a regular expression (I'm aware there's a regex tester plugin) or some series of bit-wise operations; for whatever reason its not always feasible to test directly within the project code and creating a whole new project is disruptive to the work flow.

So my question is this: what do other people use to try out their snippets of code?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Take into account IntelliJ Idea's (from version 14) [Scratches](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/scratches.html):

- Press `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+Insert` and select type

[image]

Comment: i take back what i said earlier lol. i thought this was a useless feature but rather than that, it was just realy hrad for me to find out how to "RUN the scratch." you can't do it by right-clicking the file at the moment

Comment: Along with [QuokkaJS](https://quokkajs.com/) this is really awesome thing :)

Answer (score 9):

#### Java 9

You can use **jshell** from any command line (or from the **IntelliJ terminal**).

1. **View** > **Tool Windows** > **Terminal** (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>)
2. Type **`jshell`**:

   ```
   user@xyz:~/IdeaProjects/prj$ jshell
   |  Welcome to JShell -- Version 9-ea
   |  For an introduction type: /help intro


   jshell>
   ```
3. Enter your snippet (you don't need to add `;` at the end of the row)

   ```
   jshell> Set.of("c", "b", "a").size()
   $1 ==> 3
   ```
4. Exit from `jshell` using one of the following approaches:

   - type `/exit`
   - press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

I have a "CodePlay" project that exists completely locally (i.e. the sources are local and not in the SCM sandbox) and just add standalone classes to it when I need to play around with some simple code.

I understand this isn't exactly what you wanted ("dispose of the whole thing when I close the context") but since IntelliJ will let you open a project in a new window I don't find it to be disruptive of my main work since the "CodePlay" project window can be minimized or closed without affecting the "real" project window.

Yes, there's the overhead of setting it up once, but once the project is set up it loads pretty quickly because there's not much in it and what is in it is pretty short.

Comment: Once again the obvious answer seems to be the best one...or at least the safest.

Comment: This was definitely the best answer in 2011 but as Felix points out, IDEA 14 and later have the new "Scratches" feature which provide the desired behavior right out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

My method to test code is using JUnit and a temporary class. In the class I will create a single zero arg method with a JUnit @Test annotation. The code I am playing with will be inside the method, and then a simple key stroke will run that code.

Comment: Thats what I've been doing for the most part too...every now and then I forget to exclude the test classes from vcs tho and end up having to deal with that.  So much for a perfect solution :p

Comment: I tend to put all off mine in a "Scratch.java" class and add that same class to my .gitignore file. Never gets added that way :)

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend [compileonline.com](http://www.compileonline.com/compile_java_online.php) which can be great for testing small snippets

Comment: Super-like this option.

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028605/intellij-idea-eclipse-scrapbook-equivalent). Groovy shell (in IDEA) is a command-line application that lets you evaluate Groovy expressions, functions, define classes and run Groovy commands. The Groovy shell can be launched in Groovy projects and in Grails applications.

*Stop* 
Ctrl+F2  Click this button to stop the current process.

*Close* 
Ctrl+Shift+F4  Click this button to close the selected tab of the Run tool window and terminate the current process.

*Execute Groovy Code* (Ctrl+Enter) Run code, entered in the console.

*Help* F1  Use this icon or shortcut to open the corresponding help page.

and I'll be trying this myself

Comment: +1 Since I can use classes inside my project in the snippets of code. That was exactly what I was looking for.