# Intellij Idea - Eclipse Scrapbook equivalent

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

Is there an equivalent to [Eclipse's "Scrapbook"](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-create_scrapbook_page.htm) feature in Intellij Idea?

(Before I go looking for 3rd party plugins)

I've had a "[google](http://bit.ly/KWXs1g)" around, to no avail...

Comment: Vic's answer below regarding the Groovy Shell is exactly what I was after... (even though I'm not using Groovy), it works well, I hadn't noticed the Groovy Shell before as I had the Groovy plugin disabled...

Comment: nb: See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140228 for the latest status on intellij executable java scratch files

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For some basic functionality you can use [Groovy Shell](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/groovy-shell.html) (obviously it can also run Java code)

Comment: Just tried it, pretty much what I was after, thanks Vic, good man :)

Answer (score 6):

The actual equivalent are [scratch files](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/scratches.html).

Comment: I see. In this case 'scratch files' is the answer. The link simply saves you looking thus up in IntelliJ help.

Comment: Sadly, scratch files are *not* equivalent to Eclipse scrapbook. Read the details of the discussion at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140228

Comment: Scratch-Files are indeed a little different in that they have to represent a complete class with main method if you want to run them, but that's often close enough. They can draw resources from the whole project, so that's even a little easier than in Eclipse.