# How to quickly run a static code snippet in Java using an IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, static-analysis

I'd like to quickly check the result of a static method I'm analyzing, within the IDE if possible.

```
public static int foo(int a, int b){
    return (a & 11) ^ b;
}
```

For example, right-click the expression and run it, something like

```
> foo(11, 2)
> 9
> foo(28, 3)
> 11
```

I don't know the result in advance (the actual code is more complicated), so unit testing is out of the question.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible in any IDE. For IntelliJ instructions look here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-applications.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a Unit Test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751553/how-to-write-a-unit-test)

Comment: Eclipse: see [Creating a Java Scrapbook Page](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-create_scrapbook_page.htm)

Comment: I don't want to run tests, I want to run a function from a code snippet and get its result. Unit tests imply that I know the result, which I don't in my case (not this code which is over-simplified).
Also I can't run the application, so I can't [evaluate an expression](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/evaluating-expressions.html) either. My only option is static analysis and running snippets like this.
@howlger I think you found it. Also on Intellij https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028605/intellij-idea-eclipse-scrapbook-equivalent

Comment: If you're on Java 9, the `jshell` might work for you too.

Comment: This is indeed not a case of unit testing. But how can you write a method where you don't know the output ? I don't know you, but I am used to have specification to write code, which mean that for specific inputs, an output is provided. Complicated or not, you should already have at least a few test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Eclipse** there are the so-called ***Java Scrapbook Pages***: see [Eclipse Help - Creating a Java Scrapbook Page](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-create_scrapbook_page.htm)

**Since Java 9** there is the so-called ***JShell*** which can also be used without an IDE: see [Oracle Help Center - Introduction to JShell](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm)

Java 9 ***JShell*** can be used from IntelliJ IDEA: Tools | **JSHell Console...** action.

Answer (score 1):

If using IntelliJ and Java 9+, you can access jshell, the repl that comes with Java 9 and above. That allows you to paste your method definition into the jshell console and then run it with different parameters.

See https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/09/java-9-and-intellij-idea/ for more details (the actual JShell section is halfway down, and apparently has no direct link)

Comment: You still need to copy past the method to `jShell` ? So there is no added value using intellij. They just provide a shortcut to `jshell`. That's too bad. It would have been useful that it "pre-load" the method instead of having to copy-paste it.

Comment: @AxelH the advantage is that it sets the classpath of your project.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 9, you can use the `jshell` as mentioned in other answers.

If not, you can still use unit tests. Technically, a unit test does not need to have an assertion. You can have any code in your unit test, which means that you can also have something like this:

```
@Test
public void getMyResult(){
    System.out.ptintln(foo(1,10));
}
```

Obviously, you shouldn't commit this test into your source code repo as the test is badly designed (it will always pass unless `foo` throws an exception) but for your purpose, it might do the trick.

**Edit:**

As @AxelH said in the comments, you can also create a simple `main` method.

Comment: That's not really a @Test. Just create a `main` method then. That would be the same.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I actually didn't even think about creating a `main` method. I added it to my answer, thanks for the idea :)

Comment: On the other hand, depending on the project/setup, it might be easier to create such a `@Test` than creating a main method.